# There is a lot of text

Tags: plural-forms, singular

I was in an interview and answering an online test. The teacher asked me how I was doing. I said to him that 'there is a lot of text but it's ok.'

Is the phrase "there is a lot of text" correct is it possible to say "there are..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  "Text" can function as a countable noun (meaning "a book") and as an uncountable noun (meaning "writing"). As an uncountable noun, it should be treated as singular. You should say "There is a lot of text". "There are a lot of texts" would be wrong - text is not countable when it is used in the sense of website text.